# SVG foreignObject not catching onClick event (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, svg

I'm using [React Digraph](https://github.com/uber/react-digraph) to create an interface where a user can create and edit state machines. The interface is somewhat usable (at least in terms of creating or deleting nodes through keyboard shortcuts), but I need to update the interface itself so the user can do this only using the mouse. To this end, I imagined the following interface:

[image: interface]

In terms of code, this was pretty easy. Regarding the API, I just had to override the method `renderNode`, and use the `foreignObject` element to insert HTML onto the SVG being used by the API:

```
public renderNode = (nodeRef: any, data: any, id: string, selected: boolean, hovered: boolean) => {
    const positioning = data.type === 'required' ? styles.required : styles.optional;
    return (
      <g className={`shape`}>
        {!selected ? null : (
          <foreignObject x="-77" y="-77" width="154" height="77" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <i className={`fas fa-edit ${styles.btn} ${positioning} ${styles.edit}`} />
            <i
              className={`fas fa-minus-square ${styles.btn} ${positioning} ${styles.delete}`}
              onClick={() => {
                console.log('onClick');
                this.deleteNode(id);
              }}
            />
          </foreignObject>
        )}
        <use
          className={`node ${hovered ? 'hovered' : ''} ${selected ? 'selected' : ''}`}
          x="-77"
          y="-77"
          width="154"
          height="154"
          xlinkHref={`#${data.type}`}
        >
          <svg viewBox="-27 0 154 154" id={data.type} width="154" height="154">
            <rect transform="translate(50) rotate(45)" width="109" height="109" />
          </svg>
        </use>
      </g>
    );
  };
```

Now, everything should be working according to plan, but for some reason, the `onClick` event is not being caught. No console.log shows, and no `deleteNode` function is being called.

I'm using:

```
    "react": "^16.6.1",
    "react-digraph": "^6.0.0",
    Google Chrome Version 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
After James Delaney's suggestion, I tried to add references and, subsequently, event listeners to all the nodes available. Since I'm potentially getting the machine's info from the backend, I can't statically create all the references. As such, I tried to create a 'reference list' on `componentDidMount`, after getting the nodes, and call the `addEventListener` method on all nodes found, adding the event listeners to this list and connecting the references when the nodes get rendered. In practice, this is the `componentDidMount`:

```
public componentDidMount(): void {
    const { machine } = this.props;
    this.setState({ graph: machine ? stateMachineToGraph(machine) : initialGraph }, () => {
      this.state.graph.nodes.forEach(node => {
        const del = `${node.id}delete`,
          edit = `${node.id}edit`;
        this[del].addEventListener('click', this.deleteNode(node.id));
        this[edit].addEventListener('click', this.editNode(node.id));
      });
    });
  }
```

And this would be the `foreignObject` stated earlier:

```
<foreignObject x="-77" y="-77" width="154" height="77" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <i
              ref={edit => (this[`${id}edit`] = edit)}
              className={`fas fa-edit ${styles.btn} ${positioning} ${styles.edit}`}
            />
              <i
                ref={del => (this[`${id}delete`] = del)}
                className={`fas fa-minus-square ${styles.btn} ${positioning} ${styles.delete}`}
              />
          </foreignObject>
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working, and I've tried iterating over this solution using lists explicitly or using refs statically (for test purposes). No progress was made.

**Edit 2**:
Considering the possible solution above, I iterated a bit more and added the event listeners **only when** the nodes were rendered. As such, the `renderNode` method became like this:

```
public renderNode = (nodeRef: any, data: any, id: string, selected: boolean, hovered: boolean) => {
    console.log(id);
    if (this[`${id}edit`] && this[`${id}delete`]) {
      this[`${id}edit`].addEventListener('click', this.editNode(id));
      this[`${id}delete`].addEventListener('click', this.deleteNode(id));
    }
    const positioning = data.type === 'required' ? styles.required : styles.optional;
...
```

For now I'm not testing if the event listeners are already present for a specific node, I'll do that further on. For this implementation, I can finally delete nodes, but it's not recognizing the 'click' event. I simply hover on a node and the event is triggered (along with the 'edit' event) and the node gets deleted. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste a code of deleteNode function?

Comment: Sure. However, I haven't been able to test it, since, as I stated, it isn't called:

public deleteNode = id => {
    const { graph } = this.state;
    graph.nodes.splice(0, 1);
    graph.nodes = [...this.state.graph.nodes.filter(node => node.id !== id)];
    this.setState({
      graph,
    });
  };

Answer (score 1):

- Try with puting ref on svg element
- on componentDidMount add click event listener to the ref
- remove event listener in componentWillUnmount

For Example:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.ref.addEventListener('click', this.deleteNode(id));
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    this.ref.removeEventListener('click', this.deleteNode(id));
}
```

}

I am not sure this is solution, but you can try.

Comment: I hoped that would work, but unfortunately it didn't. It seems the graph doesn't render initially, and as such whenever I add an event listener to a reference, it comes out undefined... Haven't found a way to make this work, unfortunately, but I'll update the main post with this try. Thanks for the input.